# Infinite metric space has a infinite open set whose complement is also infinite

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

let $d$ be a metric on an infinite set $M$. prove that there is an open set $U$ in $M$ such that both $U$ and its complement are infinite.

Hint is given that either $(M,d)$ is discrete or it is not.

case of discrete is done. but what about the case when $(M,d)$ is not discrete.it mean it has at least one subset which is not open. how from this can i find a infinite open set ,whose complement is also infinite.

any hint.thank in advanced

Comment: Hint: the fact that it is nondiscrete means there exists a point so that every ball centered at that point has infinitely many points. Try proving this.

Comment: Something seems missing. What do you mean with "infinite"? Infinitely many points? Unbounded? In the first case this question is purely set theoretical. In the second case: its wrong, just take a bounded metric space.

Comment: @M.Winter: It's the first case and it's not purely set-theoretic as the question is to find an open set with the given property. You need to use the fact that it's a metric space. Otherwise the coarse topology on an infinite set would be a counterexample.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip  My fault. Thank your for clarifying this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $M$ is not discrete, there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ of distinct points that converges to some limit $L$. Let $A=\{x_{2n}:n\ge1\}\cup\{L\}$ and $U=M\setminus A$.